# Hyperparameter Optimization for a Machine Learning Algorithm

Tags: classification, svm, class-imbalance, hyperparameter-tuning

I have a question regarding Hyperparameter Optimization for a Machine Learning Algorithm.

I try to fit a Support Vector Classifier and use Hyperparameter-Tuning (but it could be also another classifier).

My classes are highly imbalanced (20% of one class, lets call it “red” and 80% of the other, lets call it “black”).

Now, the objective of my Hyperparameter-Optimization is the cross-validation loss.

If, say, 20% of the observations are “reds” and 80% are “black”, then a really bad classifier would just label every case as “black” and achieve on average a cross-validation loss of 20%.

Now my question: If I see that the objective of my Hyperparamer-Optimization does not fall significantly below 20%, I could infer that it is useless without further analyzing. Correct? Or is there something I do not understand correctly?

This happens in all optimizations I am running now. I could conclude that my features are not informative.

I guess I have to change the objective for the hyperparameter optimization routine? (If my package allows for that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your error stays at about 20%, it sounds like your features are not really helping.

It is likely the case that your relationship in data/features is not simple, so you need to allow your SVM model more flexibility and/or train for longer. This will of course bring in the danger of overfitting, but should improve things... you'll need to try out a few different things.

If you are using SciKit Learn, this might equate to using a radial basis function with a high value of argument `C` (giving much more flexibility to the model) and also try a higher value for the argument `gamma`, which will reduce the *radius of influence* of each individual data point.
[Check out this example for further explanation.](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_rbf_parameters.html)

Think of the classic example of flipping an unbiased coin: we would expect to get 50% heads and 50% tails. So in this binary prediction, any time you make a prediction, you have 50-50 odds and so a model with more than 50% error is worse than a random guess!

If you are getting 20% error, it sounds like your model is just predicting black. A simple way to see and understand this - and why it really makes sense perhaps - would be to plot the data.

If in your feature speace, the points all look like a big mixture, a cloud, where the majority of points are black, then even a human would likely just predict black:

[image]

So two options:

1. Allow the model higher flexibility (as described above), which will let it (over-)fit a line that cleanly cuts out the sparse red points from the black
2. Get new features, or preprocess your features in such a way that a plot might end up looking something more like thi the image below, which will allow a simpler model to classify the red from the black with e.g. a straight line.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are right, what has to be changed is the objective. You are currently using accuracy as a measure of how good your classifier is. Accuracy is not a good measure when you have class imbalance. For this reason, other objectives have to be used. AUC is a better measure, and so is the log-loss, although not that interpretable. However, both AUC and log-loss need you method to output probabilities, not just predictions of classes. For this reason, it is required that your SVM implementation has a predict probability method.

Comment: Thanks a lot, unfortunately I can "accept" only one answer here on stackexchange

Comment: So, my hyperparameter-search function will need AUC or log-loss as an objective. So maybe I have to adjust the code of my package accordingly?
I will look whether Python/scikit has this option. Matlab may not have this...

Comment: I am sure sklearn has this option on GridSearchCV.

Answer (score 2):

Measuring the AUC of the ROC curve provides a good measure because it allows you to evaluate the probability that a model correct classifies input vs the probability that it incorrectly classifies, as opposed to simply evaluating the number of items that were correctly classified in the training data.

There are a few tools that can help resolve this issue while searching for a good model, including one in the imblearn library found [here](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/generated/imblearn.under_sampling.RandomUnderSampler.html), which allows you to randomly undersample the dominant class so the disparity isn't so high (i.e. 80%).